# How to insert the array of records inside the range

Tags: go, go-gorm

How do I insert the struct inside the range?

```
    //Department array (department table)
    var depValues []model.Department = []model.Department{
            model.Department{DepartmentName: "Software Analyst", DeptCode: "SA"},
            model.Department{DepartmentName: "Business Analyst", DeptCode: "BA"},
    }

    for _, dep := range depValues {
            db.Create(&dep) //It's working fine
        }
```

Here, `dep.ID` return the both records `id`

```
    //Another array (employee table)
    var empValues []model.Employee = []model.Employee{
            model.Employee{EmpId: "001", EmpName: "samsung", departmentRef: dep.ID},
            model.Employee{EmpId: "002", EmpName: "Nokia", departmentRef: dep.ID},
        }
```

Now, I want to insert the `departmentId` into `employee` table, How can I do it, Any one can teach me.

**Already Tried**

It will be return duplicate values

```
var depValues []model.Department = []model.Department{
        model.Department{DepartmentName: "Software Analyst", DeptCode: "SA"},
        model.Department{DepartmentName: "Business Analyst", DeptCode: "BA"},
    }

        for _, dep := range depValues {
            db.Create(&dep)
            //Insert into Employee
            var empValues []model.Employee = []model.Employee{
                model.Employee{EmpId: "001", EmpName: "samsung", DepRefer: dep.ID},
                model.Employee{EmpId: "002", EmpName: "Nokia", DepRefer: dep.ID},
            }

            for _, empv := range empValues {
                db.Create(&empv)
            }
        }
```

Database duplicate records

```
    '1', '2018-07-10 15:12:27', '2018-07-10 15:12:27', NULL, '001', 'samsung', '1'
    '2', '2018-07-10 15:12:28', '2018-07-10 15:12:28', NULL, '002', 'Nokia', '2'
    '3', '2018-07-10 15:12:29', '2018-07-10 15:12:29', NULL, '001', 'samsung', '1'
    '4', '2018-07-10 15:12:29', '2018-07-10 15:12:29', NULL, '002', 'Nokia', '2'
```

Comment: What actually happened and what did you expect to happen? Please add these infos to your question.

Comment: Why are you nesting the loop of employee inside loop of department?

Comment: Make sure that you are setting the ID or whatever the model.Department level attribute, Is that ID type an interface{}

Comment: Because , I need Department Id so, employee used inside the loop @leafbebop

Comment: I can't understand you correctly. Can you provide some desired output?

Comment: The department table length is two, So the loop exec. two times mean while employee insert the record at four time (duplicates), So how can I solve the issue? @leafbebop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question , you have two variables and both of them are slice.You want to append one of them to another another :

this is your code and result :

```
func main() {
var depValues = []Department{
    {DepartmentName: "Software Analyst", DeptCode: "SA"},
    {DepartmentName: "Business Analyst", DeptCode: "BA"},
}

for _, dep := range depValues {
    fmt.Println(dep)
    var empValues = []Employee{
        {EmpId: "001", EmpName: "samsung", DepRefer: 1},
        {EmpId: "002", EmpName: "Nokia", DepRefer: 2},
    }

    for _, empv := range empValues {
        fmt.Println(empv)
    }
}
}
```

your result

```
 {Software Analyst SA []}
 {001 samsung 1}
 {002 Nokia 2}
 {Business Analyst BA []}
 {001 samsung 1}
 {002 Nokia 2}
```

And this my code and result

```
type Department struct {
DepartmentName string
DeptCode string
Employee []Employee
}

type Employee struct {
 EmpId string
 EmpName string
 DepRefer  int

}

 func main() {

     var depValues  = []Department{
        {DepartmentName: "Software Analyst", DeptCode: "SA"},
        {DepartmentName: "Business Analyst", DeptCode: "BA"},
    }

    var empValues  = []Employee{
        {EmpId: "001", EmpName: "samsung", DepRefer: 1},
        {EmpId: "002", EmpName: "Nokia", DepRefer: 2},
    }

    for _, dep := range depValues {
        dep.Employee = empValues
        fmt.Println(dep)
    }
 }
```

and result :

```
{Software Analyst SA [{001 samsung 1} {002 Nokia 2}]}
{Business Analyst BA [{001 samsung 1} {002 Nokia 2}]}
```